# What is pIII_sse and what its function is?

Tags: kernel

Yesterday when I turned off the splash of Ubuntu, I saw some interesting messages were printed on the screen when the system was booting.

```
xor: automatically using best checksumming function: pIII_sse

  pIII_sse  :  5651.000 MB/sec
```

I did search google, but I still couldn't find what pIII_sse definitely is.

I know it's a checksuming function, so what it is checksuming for? What does `5651.000 MB/sec` mean?

And I use athlon, why kernel uses `pIII_sse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referring to the assembly language implementation; the checksumming function's result is the same in all cases.  In this case, it means the version originally written for the Pentium 3 using the SSE extended instruction set.

The speed printed is the average number of megabytes of data it can pass to the checksumming function per second, a measure of the function's efficiency.

(And the kernel tries all the versions it knows about and uses the one with the highest MB/s; this doesn't necessarily mean one named after your particular CPU.  It is, after all, in AMD's best interests to be at *least* as fast as the equivalent Intel CPU.)

Comment: Thank you:) Is there any other checksuming functions? For example, the one is written for AMD CPU?

Comment: Not counting the generic versions, for 32-bit x86 there is also `p5_mmx` and `pII_mmx` (both of which target older instruction set extensions compared to `pIII_sse`).  Presumably AMD CPUs are served well enough by these three assembly implementations not to need a custom implementation.